# Xamarin.Forms: how to position a Circle Image above and between 2 ScrollLayout

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin.forms, scrollview, frame

I work on a **Xamarin.Forms app** containing a **HomePage** based on:

- an `Image` at the **top background of the screen**
- a **list of items** displayed in a `ScrollView`

The `ScrollView` can recover the `Image` if the list contain many informations.

This looks like this:

[image: Video]

The XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray-050}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!--  Header view  -->
        <ScrollView>
            <ContentView x:Name="headerView"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- the BoxView will be replaced by an Image -->
                    <BoxView x:Name="headerImage"
                                HeightRequest="280"
                                BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
                </Grid>
            </ContentView>
        </ScrollView>

        <!--  List view  -->
        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0"
                  RowSpacing="0"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="140" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Main container -->
                    <yummy:PancakeView CornerRadius="16,16,0,0"
                                       Padding="0,10,0,0"
                                       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray-050}"
                                       Grid.Row="1">
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                     Spacing="16" Margin="16">

                            <!-- Phone container -->
                            <yummy:PancakeView Style="{StaticResource YummyHomeFrame}"
                                                Padding="16">
                                <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Style="{StaticResource HomePageHeaderLabelStyle}"
                                            Text="Phone Number" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                            Style="{StaticResource HomePageLabelStyle}"
                                            Text="+33 6 20 10 70 40"  />
                                </Grid>
                            </yummy:PancakeView>

                            <!-- Other containers -->

                        </StackLayout>
                    </yummy:PancakeView>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I would like to display a **circle logo** between the 2 `ScrollViews`, just above the `MainContainer`, something like this:

[image: Expected rendering]

But I don't have managed to achieve this, and I don't know if it's possilbe...

Comment: Are you trying to place the circle logo between 2 scrollviews and scroll together with your header? If so, my initial thought would be ```<ScrollView><Grid><Header ContentView /> <ListView ScrollOrGrid/> <CircleLogo HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,100,0,0" /></Grid> </ScrollView>```. You should adjust the margin to make that fit on the page, just focus on the same level of header and list view.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that want the circle logo to keep showing? You could have a try with RelativeLayout to do. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout

Comment: Thank you @Shaw. Yes, I would like to place the circle logo between the 2 `ScrollViews`, and make it scroll with the List `ScrollView`, as we can see on the GIF. You suggest me to add another ScrollView as main container, and to add the `Circle` item in the main `Grid`?  I've tried this, and I've played with `Margins`, but the   `Circle`  is still displayed in the Header, not above the 2 `Layouts` (header/list).

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I've tried to play with `RelativeLayout`, but the Circle is static: I need that the Circle is scrolling with the `ListView`, as we can see on the GIF attached in the description.

Comment: @Gold.strike You could set the inner control as the relative layout to try, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Shaw and @Junior Jiang - MSFT

There are so **2 solutions**: **with** or **without** `RelativeLayout`.

The version **without** `RelativeLayout` was given by @Shaw.

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0"
        BackgroundColor="LightGray"
        x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!--  Header view  -->
        <ScrollView>
            <ContentView x:Name="headerView"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- the BoxView can be replaced by an Image -->
                    <BoxView x:Name="headerImage"
                                HeightRequest="280"
                                BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
                </Grid>
            </ContentView>
        </ScrollView>
            <!-- Content View -->
        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0"
                    RowSpacing="0"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="140" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Frame Container-->
                    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"
                            CornerRadius="16"
                            Padding="0,10,0,0"
                            BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                            Grid.Row="1">
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        Spacing="16" Margin="16,48,16,16">
                            <!-- Phone Frame -->
                            <Frame Padding="16">
                                <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="Phone Number" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                            Text="+33 6 20 10 70 40"  />
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                            <!-- Other Frames -->
                            <!-- ... -->
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <!-- No RelativeLayout positioned item -->
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                                CornerRadius="45"
                                BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
                                WidthRequest="90" HeightRequest="90"
                                VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="0,-45,0,0" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The version **with** `RelativeLayout` is based on @Junior Jiang - MSFT suggestion:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0"
        BackgroundColor="LightGray"
        x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!--  Header View  -->
        <ScrollView>
            <ContentView x:Name="headerView"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- the BoxView can be replaced by an Image -->
                    <BoxView x:Name="headerImage"
                                HeightRequest="280"
                                BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
                </Grid>
            </ContentView>
        </ScrollView>
        <!-- Content View -->
        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0"
                    RowSpacing="0"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="140" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                    <RelativeLayout>
                        <!-- Frame container -->
                        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"
                                CornerRadius="16"
                                Padding="0,10,0,0"
                                BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                                        Grid.Row="1">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        Spacing="16" Margin="16,48,16,16">
                                <!-- Phone Frame -->
                                <Frame Padding="16">
                                    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Label Text="Phone Number" />
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                            Text="+33 6 20 10 70 40"  />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Frame>
                                <!-- Other Frames -->
                                <!-- ... -->
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <!-- RelativeLayout positioned item -->
                        <BoxView CornerRadius="45"
                                BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
                                WidthRequest="90" HeightRequest="90"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                                                                Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                Property=Width, 
                                                                Factor=0.5,
                                                                Constant=-45}"
                                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                                                Type=RelativeToView,
                                                                ElementName=MainFrame,
                                                                Property=Y,Constant=-45}" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Great! If have solved it, remember to mark your answer when you have time. It will help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a try with [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout) to achieve that.

Here is similar sample code：

```
<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0"
                RowSpacing="0"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="140" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- Main container -->
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Frame CornerRadius="16" x:Name="MainFrame"
                                    Padding="0,10,0,0"
                                    BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                                    Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    Spacing="16"
                                    Margin="16">

                        <!-- Phone container -->
                        <Frame Padding="16">
                            <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="Phone Number" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                        Text="+33 6 20 10 70 40" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>

                        <!-- Other containers -->

                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
                    <BoxView CornerRadius="25"
                                BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=MainFrame, Property=Width,Factor=0.45}"
                                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=MainFrame, Property=Y,Constant=-20}"
                                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=MainFrame,  Constant=100}"
                                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=MainFrame, Constant=100}" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: In this case, the `RelativeLayout` is static and can't scroll, it's not the expected behavior.

Comment: @Gold.strike Because can not reproducing all needed effect, you could share a sample here. I will check that in local site.

Comment: You can get the full XAML source (without the circle logo) here: https://gofile.io/d/ml59CS

Comment: @Gold.strike Thanks for sharing. However, I can not download because the link will redicect to another link that can't  download. If possible, you coulld share the code in Github, it's free and convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Add you circle logo at the same level of the container.

```
                <!--  Items view  -->
                <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid
                        ColumnSpacing="0"
                        RowSpacing="0"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="140" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!--  Container  -->
                            <Frame ...>

                            <!--  Yoour logo -->
                            <Frame
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Margin="0,-40,0,0"
                                BackgroundColor="Green"
                                CornerRadius="40"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Start"
                                WidthRequest="40" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollView>
```

[image: Add logo around line 195]

Check the demo:

[image: demo]

As I didn't use the nugget package, I just replaced the pancake view with a frame. And you can adjust the logo size, margin as you wish.

Btw, your structure is a bit complex or redundant, could be a 4-level main structure as below:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">

  <!--  Header view  -->
  <BoxView (or Image).../>

  <!--  Items view  -->
  <ScrollView ...>
    <Grid ...>

      <!--  Container  -->
      <Frame ...>

      <!--  logo  -->
      <Frame (or Image)...>

    </Grid>
  </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```